# Variance confusion in the $p-$spin glass Hamiltonian model

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the Hamiltonian of the $p-$spin spherical glass model
$$H_{N,p}(\sigma) = \frac{1}{N^{\frac{p-1}{2}}} \sum_{i_1,\ldots, i_p = 1}^{N} J_{i_1,\ldots, i_p} \sigma_{i_1} \cdots \sigma_{i_p}\;,$$
where $\mathbf{\sigma} = (\sigma_1, \ldots , \sigma_N) \in S^{N-1} ( \sqrt{N})$ and $J_{i_1,\ldots , i_p} \sim \mathcal{N} (0 ,1)$ are independent centered Gaussian normal random variables. The constrain on the vector $\mathbf{\sigma}$ is
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sigma_i ^2 = 1\;.$$
Consider the function
$$f(\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}H_{N,p}(\sqrt{N} \sigma)\;.$$
The covariance is
$$\mathbb{E}[f(\mathbf{\sigma}) f(\mathbf{\sigma '})] = \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sigma_i \sigma' _i \right )^p\;.$$
The article I am reading says that $f(\sigma)$ has variance $1.$ How is this possible? The variance should be $N^p.$ Since we have the covariance, we just change the $\sigma'_i$ to $\sigma_i$ and then use the constraint formula.

Comment: As I read it, I interpreted the $\sigma$ in the definition of $f(\sigma)$ as $\sigma \in S^{N-1} (1)$, since then $\sqrt{N}\sigma \in S^{N-1}(\sqrt{N})$, which matches with the required condition on the parameter $\sigma$ in the definition of $H_{N,p}(\sigma)$. If the $\sigma$ from $f(\sigma)$ is indeed in $S^{N-1}(1)$ then $\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i^2 =1$ and the variance would be $1$.